# JAXB XJC use String as type if there is no type set in xsd

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I'm trying to generate JAXB Classes with XJC and maven-jaxb2-plugin. It works, but if there is no type specified on the element in the .xsd it uses `Object` for the Java Type. I would like it to use `String` instead.

This is my binding file:

```
<jxb:bindings
        version="1.0"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
        xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc">

    <jxb:globalBindings typesafeEnumMaxMembers="1000" collectionType="java.util.ArrayList">
        <xjc:simple/>
    </jxb:globalBindings>
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/SOME_OTHER_XSD.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='SOME_OTHER_TYPE']">
            <jxb:bindings node=".//xs:attribute[@name='Version']">
                <jxb:property name="VersionAttribute"/>
            </jxb:bindings>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/XSD_IN_QUESTION.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='TYPE_IN_QUESTION']">
            <jxb:bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='Version']">
                <jxb:javaType name="java.lang.String" parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.CollapsedStringAdapter"/>
            </jxb:bindings>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

This is how my .xsd file is structured:

```
<xs:schema
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:ns2="ns2"
        xmlns="ns"
        targetNamespace="ns"
        elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:element name="PARENT_ELEMENT" type="TYPE_IN_QUESTION"/>
    <xs:complexType name="TYPE_IN_QUESTION">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Version"/> <!-- No Type specified -->
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/C:/[PATH]/src/main/resources/META-INF/binding/binding.xjb{25,128}].
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: compiler was unable to honor this javaType customization. It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings.
...
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/C:/[PATH]/src/main/resources/META-INF/xsd/XSD_IN_QUESTION.xsd{93,41}].
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: (the above customization is attached to the following location in the schema)
```

The location in the second error is the version element in the xsd, so it at least finds the version, so the XPath should be right. I have no idea how to do this. Any help is much appreciated.

I tried to put it in the `globalBindings` with a type as well but it didn't work there, so now I'm trying to do it on one Element (before doing it everywhere else where needed, but would rather have a global solution if possible). I can change the .xsd but I would really rather not do that.

Comment: Give a try with type and attribute names **without** space (ex: TypeInQuestion).

Comment: I just changed the names to make it anonymous and more clear - seems I have done the opposite. In reality they all have no spaces. I edite the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, it is not possible to bind an **element** with "no type" (i.e. `xs:anyType`) to `java.lang.String` using `<jxb:javaType .../>`. *However*, it is possible to wrap the generated Java property in a *code injected* property that performs the desired conversion. Here's why and how...

##### Attribute versus Element

For XJC, the default XML type for an **attribute** is `xs:anySimpleType` and that is mapped to the Java **String** type unless customized. And, the **attribute** can be customized in the binding file using `<jxb:javaType .../>`. For example the approach shown here, binds the `version` attribute to Java's `BigDecimal` type. It demonstrates how `<jxb:javaType .../>` is configured for and accepted by XJC:

**[XSD_IN_QUESTION.xjb](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/no-type/src/main/resources/XSD_IN_QUESTION.xjb)**

```
<jxb:bindings node="//xs:attribute[@name='Version']">
    <jxb:property name="VersionAttribute">
        <jxb:baseType>
            <jxb:javaType name="java.math.BigDecimal"
                parseMethod="jakarta.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDecimal"
                printMethod="jakarta.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDecimal"
            />
        </jxb:baseType>
    </jxb:property>
</jxb:bindings>
```

> **Note:** ([JAXB v4.0, §7.8.2.1](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/xml-binding/4.0/jakarta-xml-binding-spec-4.0.html#conversion-using-child-element-javatype)]) This customization converts the default base type’s value for a *simple type definition* to the Java class specified by `<javaType>` name.

For XJC, the default XML type for an **element** is `xs:anyType` and that is mapped to the Java **Object** type. The `version` **element** cannot be customized using `<javaType ...>` because it is not a *simple type definition*! Any attempt to use the customization will throw this exception:

**Customization `anyType` with `javaType` will fail**

```
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2:
    compiler was unable to honor this javaType customization.
    It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings.
```

> **Note:** It is inconsistent with `xs:anyType` used by an **element** when no XML type is defined because `xs:anyType` is a *complex type definition*.

##### Demonstration

This [demo (zip)](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/releases/download/2.1.0/hisrc-higherjaxb-sample-notype-2.1.0-mvn-src.zip) can be downloaded, unpacked and run "as-is". It is a stand-alone Maven project that uses the *HiSrc HigherJAXB Maven Plugin* to generate JAXB classes from an XML Schema when the schema contains elements without a specified XML type.

You can run the demo and/or test(s) using:

```
mvn -Pexec clean compile exec:java -Dexec.args="src/test/samples/ParentElement.xml"
mvn -Ptest clean test
```

The [output](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/no-type/OUTPUT.txt) shows the test(s) result.

The demonstration project use the standard Maven layout plus optional `bash` scripts.

**hisrc-higherjaxb-sample-notype**

```
├── build-cfg.sh
├── build-inc.sh
├── build.sh
├── pom.xml
├── README.md
├── run.sh
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── org
    │   │       └── example
    │   │           ├── model
    │   │           │   └── Version.java
    │   │           └── notype
    │   │               └── Main.java
    │   └── resources
    │       ├── org
    │       │   └── example
    │       │       └── model
    │       │           └── jaxb.index
    │       ├── SOME_OTHER_XSD.xsd
    │       ├── XSD_IN_QUESTION.xjb
    │       └── XSD_IN_QUESTION.xsd
    └── test
        ├── java
        │   └── org
        │       └── example
        │           └── notype
        │               └── NoTypeTest.java
        ├── resources
        │   ├── jvmsystem.arguments
        │   ├── jvmsystem.properties
        │   └── simplelogger.properties
        └── samples
            ├── ParentElement.xml
            └── SomeOtherElement.xml
```

The [pom.xml](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/no-type/project-pom.xml) configures [hisrc-higherjaxb-maven-plugin](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb#readme) to use XJC extensions and an XJC [hisrc-hyperjaxb-annox-plugin](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb-annox#readme) to customize the code generation. The customization includes:

- Adding `@XmlRootElement` to `ParentElement.java` and `SomeOtherElement.java`
- Injecting `getVersion / setVersion` methods to implement the `String` conversion.

**pom.xml**

```
...
<!-- mvn hisrc-higherjaxb:help -Ddetail=true -->
<!-- mvn hisrc-higherjaxb:generate -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.patrodyne.jvnet</groupId>
    <artifactId>hisrc-higherjaxb-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${hisrc-higherjaxb-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <args>
                    <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                    <arg>-Xinject-code</arg>
                </args>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.patrodyne.jvnet</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hisrc-hyperjaxb-annox-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${hisrc-hyperjaxb-annox-plugin.version}</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
...
```

The JAXB binding file customized the [XSD_IN_QUESTION.xsd](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/no-type/src/main/resources/XSD_IN_QUESTION.xsd) schema by:

- Using [hisrc-hyperjaxb-annox-plugin](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb-annox#readme) to add `@XmlRootElement`

- Renaming the class per Java convention

- Renaming the property to `VersionElement` so it can be nicely wrapped
- Injecting code for the `Version` wrapper to get/set `java.lang.String`

[XSD_IN_QUESTION.xjb](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/no-type/src/main/resources/XSD_IN_QUESTION.xjb)

```
...
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="XSD_IN_QUESTION.xsd">
    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='PARENT_ELEMENT']/xs:complexType">
        <anx:annotate>@jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement(name = "PARENT_ELEMENT")</anx:annotate>
        <jxb:class name="ParentElement"/>
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='Version']">
            <jxb:property name="VersionElement"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
        <ci:code>
public String getVersion() { return (getVersionElement() != null) ? getVersionElement().toString() : null; }
public void setVersion(String version) { setVersionElement(new org.example.model.Version(version)); }
        </ci:code>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
...
```

For testing, an XML instance of `PARENT_ELEMENT` provides a non-trivial representation of the `Version` element to emphasize that it is an `xs:anyType`. In fact, it can be an arbitrarily complex type, which provides some insight as to why the spec limits the `xs:javaType` binding to *simple type definition*, see [JAXB v4.0, §7.8.2.1](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/xml-binding/4.0/jakarta-xml-binding-spec-4.0.html#conversion-using-child-element-javatype).

[ParentElement.xml](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/no-type/src/test/samples/ParentElement.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PARENT_ELEMENT xmlns:ns1="http://example.org/notype">
    <ns1:Version xsi:type="version" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <major>10</major>
        <minor>2</minor>
    </ns1:Version>
</PARENT_ELEMENT>
```

When JAXB unmarshals `PARENT_ELEMENT`, it uses a custom [Version.java](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/no-type/src/main/java/org/example/model/Version.java) implemented by the project and provided to the JAXB context. This class has its own namespace and demonstrates the flexibility of `xs:anyType`.

> **Note:** A [jaxb.index](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/no-type/src/main/resources/org/example/model/jaxb.index) resource file lists the non-schema-derived classes, namely the java to schema binding, in a package to register with `JAXBContext`.

The custom class implements a constructor to parse a version using the standard format (i.e. "10.2") into its major and minor parts. And a `toString()` method to return the major/minor parts as a version string.

[Version.java](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/no-type/src/main/java/org/example/model/Version.java)

```
...
public Version(String version)
{
    if ( version != null )
    {
        String[] parts = version.split("\\.");
        setMajor(parts[0]);
        if ( parts.length > 1 )
            setMinor(parts[1]);
    }
}
...
public String toString()
{
    return format("%s.%s",
        ((getMajor() != null) ? getMajor() : "0"),
        ((getMinor() != null) ? getMinor() : "0")
    );
}
...
```

XJC reads the binding file [XSD_IN_QUESTION.xjb](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/no-type/src/main/resources/XSD_IN_QUESTION.xjb) and the XML schema [XSD_IN_QUESTION.xsd](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/no-type/src/main/resources/XSD_IN_QUESTION.xsd) to generate this class (and other classes):

**ParentElement.java**

```
package org.example.notype;

import java.io.Serializable;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "versionElement" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "PARENT_ELEMENT")
public class ParentElement implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 20230701L;

    @XmlElement(name = "Version", namespace = "http://example.org/notype", required = true)
    protected Object versionElement;

    public Object getVersionElement() { return versionElement; }
    public void setVersionElement(Object value) { this.versionElement = value; }

    public String getVersion() { return (getVersionElement() != null) ? getVersionElement().toString() : null; }
    public void setVersion(String version) { setVersionElement(new org.example.model.Version(version)); }
}
```

The `ParentElement` class is bound to the root "PARENT_ELEMENT" and provides an `java.lang.Object` field to represent the "Version" sub-element. The sub-element is bound to the get/set `VersionElement` property which was custom named in the binding file.

Finally, the `ParentElement` class provides an addition get/set `Version` property to wrap the JAXB bound property and perform the Object to String conversion.

For usage, see [`org.example.notype.Main`](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/no-type/src/main/java/org/example/notype/Main.java) and [`org.example.notype.NoTypeTest`](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/no-type/src/test/java/org/example/notype/NoTypeTest.java).

*Disclaimer:* I am the maintainer for the *Patrodyne HiSrc* projects.